# Linux OS with GUI based multiple vlan support

Tags: linux, vlan, trunk, 802.1

Is there a distribution of Linux that includes support in the gui for managing 802.1q (trunks)

We have techs in the field that may need to change from one vlan to another but don't know Linux CLI at all.

Thank you,
Ken

Comment: Hire better staff?  Setting up VLANs is simple/trivial Debian-based distros IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of [NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) (0.9.4) is supposed to have added support for VLANs. Whether it's yet in your distribution of choice is another question, though.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend changing an existing distribution to accommodate this single feature request.

I don't know of any GUI that can help define vlan configurations, but assuming your deployed systems are similar, it may make sense to either document the process to make vlan changes from the command line *or* automate/script the process to make it more technician-friendly.

Which distribution are you currently using?